# nstextview diable-like behavior on selection and input

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextView:

```
NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] init];
[textView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[textView setDrawsBackground:NO];
[textView setRichText:YES];
[textView setSelectable:YES];
[textView setEditable:YES];


return textView;
```

This textView is added to subclass of NSView, in initWithFrame: I call

```
[[self window] makeFirstResponder:self.textView];
```

Furthermore, the `[self.textView acceptsFirstResponder] == YES`

But, the selection in this textView becomes gray, input not working. When I press right mouse, menu pops up, and then behavior becomes like it was expected (the blue one with working input).

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was some view pulling first responder to itself.
Just use [[self window] firstResponder] to find whom to blame in a case you have same issue.